# javaFxPorts When I Going back from google map to my app. it start from the beginning. WHY?

Tags: lifecycle, gluon-mobile, javafxports

In javaFxPorts
When I run anther app from my gluon app and go back to my app it start from the beginning and I lose all data that I got it from SQLite
:(
what is the problem?

Comment: Usually that means that you have a crash, and the app is restarted again from the scratch. Try to add some printouts to your application, deploy again, and check the console with `adb logcat`. Find out if you have an exception when the app gets paused.

Comment: @JoséPereda I try to create **new Project Gluon Mobile - multi View project (FXML)** and i got same problem
maybe because of The nag screen and i must get license but I am not sure.

Comment: The license has nothing to do with your issue. You can deploy your project without it (you will see the nag screen only).

Comment: @JoséPereda [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B560wzZgNWw) I made this video expline the problem.

finally I found out what the problem was. The problem is only in my mobile phone. The app itself tested on another device and there is no problem. I must reset my device :(
but other apps dasn't have any problem.
Thanks